DNS issue on Rocky Linux 8 between virtual machines
I have a setup with 3 virtual machines running Rocky Linux 8:

VM1 is connected to VM2 and connected to NatNetwork
VM2 is connected to VM3.
Ping works in all directions using IP addresses, so IP addresses and routes are configured correctly.
All VMs have internet access (e.g., ping 8.8.8.8 works on all machines).

I’ve installed a DNS server on VM1 (Bind). The DNS setup partially works:

From VM1, I can resolve domain names for VM2 and VM3 using ping.
From VM2, I can resolve domain names for VM1 using ping.

Problem: From VM3, I cannot resolve domain names for VM1 or VM2. The error message is: unknown domain name.
On both VM2 and VM3, I’ve set the DNS server in /etc/resolv.conf like this:
nameserver VM1-IP-address
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

"ping works in all directions". Can you be more specific? Did you ping from VM3 to VM1, and then again from VM1 to VM3? VM2 needs to have packet forwarding enabled, and VM1 needs to know to use VM2 as a route to VM3. Did you do all that?
If that ping works, then I'd ensure all firewalls are disabled on all three VMs (at least temporarily).

@JeremyImpson I did all that. I have now temporarily disabled the firewall on VM3 and VM2 and VM3 resolves the domain name for VM1. Why did I have to turn it off? What is the reason?

As we discussed in comments, disabling the firewall allowed name resolution to work as expected, from VM3 as the DNS client to VM1 as DNS server, through VM2 as an IP router.
This means that some firewall or other was blocking name service requests. It's not obvious to me which firewall ruleset is at fault--because pings to 8.8.8.8 worked previously, as did name service requests from VM2 to VM1. And it could be that more than one ruleset is to blame.
First, turn back on the firewall on VM1. If the problem recurs, then VM1's rulset is probably blocking packets from unrecognized IP ranges. Since VM3 is not directly connected to VM1, it's being denied. Hopefully adding a rule to its INPUT chain that explicitly accept packets from VM3 will solve that problem.
Second, turn back on the firewall on VM2. If the problem recurs, then VM2's ruleset probably needs an ALLOW rule added to its FORWARD chain. I'd start with an any to any rule to make sure it works, then make it more specific if you want greater security. It all depends on what you want to do with your little VM environment.
Third, turn back on the firewall on VM3. I don't expect that this firewall ruleset was causing any problems, but if it was, add a rule allowing packets from VM1.
